# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "transformer" (type Transformer)

Tags: python, tensorflow, transformer-model

So I code a Transformers neural network that works as an ASR, it works, it trains good and saved the model as...

```
model.save("savedmodel.model")
```

The problem is that when I want to predict, I do this..

```
speech_model = load_model('D:\DOT\Speechrecognition\speechrecognitionE.model')

path = "D:\DOT\Speechrecognition\Data\LJSpeech-1.1\wavs\LJ001-0001.wav"

def path_to_audio(path):
    # spectrogram using stft
    audio = tf.io.read_file(path)
    audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio, 1)
    audio = tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)
    stfts = tf.signal.stft(audio, frame_length=200, frame_step=80, fft_length=256)
    x = tf.math.pow(tf.abs(stfts), 0.5)
    # normalisation
    means = tf.math.reduce_mean(x, 1, keepdims=True)
    stddevs = tf.math.reduce_std(x, 1, keepdims=True)
    x = (x - means) / stddevs
    audio_len = tf.shape(x)[0]
    # padding to 10 seconds
    pad_len = 2754
    paddings = tf.constant([[0, pad_len], [0, 0]])
    x = tf.pad(x, paddings, "CONSTANT")[:pad_len, :]
    return x

x = path_to_audio(path)
#print(x)
speech_model.predict(x)
```

The path to audio function, converts the audio path to an spectrogram, in the training model it receive audio spectrograms as inputs, but it show this error..

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\berna\Desktop\Programming\AI_ML_DL\Projects\DOT\DOT-alpha.py", line 72, in <module>
    speech_model.predict(x)
File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 1129, in autograph_handler
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1621, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1611, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1604, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1572, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "transformer" (type Transformer).

    Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
    Positional arguments (2 total):
        * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(None, 129), dtype=float32)
        * False
    Keyword arguments: {}

    Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):

    Option 1:
    Positional arguments (2 total):
        * [TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 129), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/0'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 199), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/1')]
        * False
    Keyword arguments: {}

    Option 2:
    Positional arguments (2 total):
        * [TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 129), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/0'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 199), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/1')]
        * True
    Keyword arguments: {}

    Option 3:
    Positional arguments (2 total):
        * [TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 129), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 199), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_2')]
        * False
    Keyword arguments: {}

    Option 4:
    Positional arguments (2 total):
        * [TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 129), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 199), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_2')]
        * True
    Keyword arguments: {}

    Call arguments received:
    • args=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 129), dtype=float32)',)
    • kwargs={'training': 'False'}
```

What does that means? what is wrong with the prediction?

Comment: If the whole transformer model code is useful, Is super similar to this one https://keras.io/examples/audio/transformer_asr/

Comment: could you show just the model part of your code?

Comment: @catasaurus The model is the same code as the one from the link

Comment: @catasaurus idk why I can't add the code :/ but the link is in the comments

Comment: Conv1D layers need a 3D input shape. You have a 2D input shape. Have you tried reshaping your input to `None, None, 129`?

Comment: @catasaurus nope, I haven't how can i do it?

Comment: `tf.reshape((None, None, 129))` should work to reshape your input tensor. It might not stop the error from showing but it is worth a try.

Comment: @catasaurus now the error is this one   """File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 1090, in op_dispatch_handler
    result = api_dispatcher.Dispatch(args, kwargs)
TypeError: Missing required positional argument """

Comment: @catasaurus but the other one disappear

Comment: @catasaurus any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242925/discussion-between-catasaurus-and-bernardo-olisan).

Comment: the above comment were i told you to try `tf.reshape` has an error. I wrote it too quickly. I gave you the right way to try it in the chat